# how convert x = ['30+20'] string to int

Tags: python, list

Simple question from a simple guy..

How i convert x = ['30+20'] or x = ['1-500'] list string to int ?

Im trying to get out the operation of that list[string].

x = [50] or x = [-499]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. **Why** do you want to do this? Where does the data come from? And what is so important about the list? If you can do this for an individual string, it should be easy to repeat for an entire list, right?

Answer (score 1):

```
x = ['30+20'] 
print(sum([int(i) for i in x[0].split('+')]))
```

this gives just int without list 
if you need it inside of list just wrap it into `list()`